# How to trim long links with CSS3?

Tags: css, hyperlink, trim, ellipsis

When dealing with trimming long links we have to do extra work server side like checking string length and adding ellipsis if it's to long but we can do it easily just with CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer how to do it:

```
/* Only links with "href" attribute */
a[href] {
    /* Add ellipsis at the end if text does not fit in given width */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    /* Have to add this line to make upper line work */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Decide what is the longest link width in given units (px, em, rem etc.) */
    max-width: 300px;
    /* Element has to be inline-block to have width and fit inline in the same time */
    display: inline-block;
    /* We want to have all the link in one line without wrapping */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Here's a sample of the above: http://codepen.io/BJack/pen/bBryi

The only suggestion I would make to enhance this answer, would be for SEO purposes to add the same link text as the Title and/or Alt attributes so that on hover the user can still see the full title, and search engines have some extra context on the link. Great answer @Jagi!

Comment: This.  The ellipsis is an awesome addition to our toolbox.